# Не импортирует зависимости exoplayer в android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Использую exoplayer

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.0'
```

Но эти зависимости горят красным, как исправить?

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaCodecSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultUriDataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

По ощущению импорты уже устарели. Видимо библиотека обновилась и использует уже другие адреса для импорта. К примеру так все нормально импортируется.
Да и вообще пользуйтесь автоимпортом.

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer;
```

Comment: Подскажите как использвать автоимпорт?

Comment: @Buratino Apps После того как вы добавили нужные вам зависимости в приложение, начните набирать ваш код в нужном месте. IDE вам либо предложит название для класса и сама импортирует его, либо выделит красным и подчеркнет, тогда кликните по нему, нажмите alt+enter и добавьте необходимый импорт из предложенных.